# Configuring zabbix to monitor ping from a server

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I am new to zabbix. I would like to monitor the ping from my server and I want to activate a trigger if the ping gets unresponsive or ping time exceeds 20 milliseconds.

I don't know how to configure the trigger expression to suit my needs. Please help. Thanks.

I used

```
type -> Simple check
key -> icmppingsec
Type of information -> Numeric(Float)
Units -> s
Flexible intervial -> 10secs, from 7:00-24:00
```

[image]

This is the trigger expression.

[image]

And a graph I created.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [simple check documentation](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/simple_checks), `icmppingsec` item returns ping time in seconds or 0 if the host is not reachable. Therefore, your trigger can be as follows:

```
{Template ICMP Ping:icmppingsec.avg(5m)} > 0.020 |
{Template ICMP Ping:icmppingsec.max(5m)} = 0
```

If you are using at least Zabbix 2.4, you should use `or` instead of `|` (see [What's new in Zabbix 2.4.0](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/2.4/manual/introduction/whatsnew240#support_of_new_trigger_operators)).

Note also that there is no point in using "1-7,00:00-24:00" flexible interval. You can just put "10" into "Updated interval (in sec)" field.

Comment: What does icmppingsec.max(5m)} = 0 means?

Comment: Since "icmppingsec item returns ping time in seconds or 0 if the host is not reachable", it means that the host was not reachable for five minutes, i.e., the item always returned 0.